# Graph-tool Overlap Block Object

Tags: graph-tool

How do you convert the block memberships for each node in an overlap block state into a numpy array?

Specifically, when inferring an overlapping block object, it looks like the overlapping membership array can be recovered with

```
blockobject = gt.minimize_blockmodel_dl(g, overlap = True)
blockpropertyvector = blockobject.get_overlap_blocks()[0]
```

To convert this into a numpy array, it seems we need to have an idea of the maximum number of memberships for any given node (lets call it max_overlaps) and then we can convert to a 2d array

```
blockpropertyvector.get_2d_array(range(max_overlaps))
```

But now I'm not sure how to interpret the result.  Is it true that the first row of this matrix is the first membership assignment for each node?  If so, then I would want to say that the second row is the second membership assignment for a node if it exists, and 0 otherwise.  But 0 is a possible block number, so how do we know if the 0-ith block contains an overlapping membership?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, in this way you will not be able to distinguish lack of membership from a membership to group zero.

I think the simplest thing you can do is simply loop over the nodes:

```
bv = state.get_overlap_blocks()[0]
b = zeros((g.num_vertices(), max_B))
for v in g.vertices():
    b[int(v),:len(b[v])] = bv[v].a + 1
```

With the above, the value zero means lack of membership, and a value of r > 0 means membership to group r - 1.

Comment: I think the right choice in the last string would this:
`:len(bv[v].a)` instead of `:len(b[v])` because the last one every time returns `max_B` value